# curve fitting in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

Is there any opencv function for curve fitting?

I have a set of points (cv::points) and my aim is to fit these points to a closed/open curve.

Right now I am taking a pair of points and drawing lines with them, effectively forming a curve.

Answer (score 2):

It's not quite clear from your question whether you want to smooth the curve by adding more points or to summarise it by using fewer points. If it's the latter, perhaps you should consider `cv::approxPolyDP`, which is [documented here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=approxpoly#approxpolydp) and copied below for reference.

[image: docs]

Comment: I actually want to calculate the equation of a curve which fits these points

Comment: After which I would like to move the curve across the image by keeping its curvature as it is. Sorry for the late response. Thanks in advance

Comment: @AdiPiratla Ok, I see, well there's nothing in OpenCV that will help with curve fitting so you probably need to look for a library that offers something like [LMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm) and feed it your OpenCV data to get the curve.

Comment: Does LMA stand for Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm? I was looking at that. I found one library http://apps.jcns.fz-juelich.de/doku/sc/lmfit. I will update if it proves useful

Comment: @AdiPiratla That's right - I put the link to wikipedia in my comment above.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are talking function approximation and interpolation.

As I know, there's not a function directly about curve fitting.

If you just want to get the fitting result, you can use Matlab's *curve fitting* toolbox, where there is a tool named **cftool**. **cftool** is a GUI tool, you can specify the input points and the interpolation method and get the result formula.